# Magento media folder from UAT to local

Tags: magento

I copied media folder and the database from UAT to my local so that I can have the product pages ready with images on my local.

Now I delete the media folder on my local and put the UAT media folder and also uploaded the new UAT database.

Now Everything is working ok, I can get the content but except the images.

Magento is not picking up the product images or other images which I can see in wysiwyg editor.

I cleared the cache and product cache as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you flush the Catalog Image Cache?
[image]

Edit:
Also there is [an article with some more items to do/check](http://www.file2cart.com/blog/6582-what-to-do-when-magento-products-images-categories-do-not-show-up):
1. Make sure to recursively change the file permissions in magento/media to "777" (full read/write/exec access)

2. On the Images Tab, make sure there is at least one image uploaded for the product, that the Excluded checkbox isn’t checked, and the radios to include it for thumbnail, base image, and small image are selected for the respective images.
3. Under System->Configuration->Catalog->Product Image Placeholders, make sure there is a default image uploaded for each of the respective image types
4. Remove the .htaccess file located in the magento/media folder